# Way to output the list of prime numbers between 1-100 without using Risk Aster's method

Tags: sas

I am trying to learn a way to print the prime numbers between 1-100 using simple sas codes.

There is a method in this book, which however I want to avoid:
Prime number sieve, pages 533-534 "Professional SAS Programming Secrets" Rick Aster and Rhena Seidman. First edition 1991

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is Rick's method that you want to avoid?  What have you tried (please show code)?  Seems you could try some brute force looping, and use the MOD function inside a loop as a test.

Comment: Prime number sieve, pages 533-534 "Professional SAS Programming Secrets" Rick Aster and Rhena Seidman. First edition 1991

Comment: Thanks @data_null_ I think I've got it on the shelf at work.  Luckily Rick has posted it on his site as well. http://www.globalstatements.com/shortcuts/88a.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is defining your algorithm. 
You first need to loop from 1 to 100

```
data primes;
do i=1 to 100;
   *classification code;
end;
run;
```

Then you need to define your algorithm. In this case, a prime is divisible by an number less than the number. You can brute force it and test every number that is lesser - which adds another loop. This loop needs to start at 2, since all numbers are divisible by 1.

```
data primes;
do i=1 to 100;
    do j=2 to i-1;
   *classification code;
    end;
end;
run;
```

You classification rule now needs to be defined. In SAS we can use the MOD() function to get the remainder of a division operation. A prime number will never have a remainder that is 0.

```
data primes;
do i=1 to 100;
    do j=2 to i-1;
        if mod(i, j) = 0 then do;
            status='Composite';
            leave; *exit loop;
        end;
    end;
end;
run;
```

We can refine the code by adding the initial status of `prime` and using an explicit `output` to view the results. A number that is never divisible retains the status of prime, while the others are assigned to composite.

```
data primes;
length status $12.;
do i=1 to 100;
    status='Prime';
    do j=2 to i-1;
        if mod(i, j) = 0 then do;
            status='Composite';
            leave; *exit loop;
        end;
    end;
output;
end;
run;
```

Comment: You don't need quite that much force (or is it that much brute) for the brute force method. The upper bound for the inner loop can by i/2 instead of i-1.

Comment: @tom Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: An even lower upper bound would be sqrt(i).